# Button click method is scrolling to top of page instead of performing action

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am designing an Angular 2 app that allows for a user to cancel the screen they are on and go back a page.  While this works, the first click of the button causes the page to scroll to the top, and a subsequent button press causes the intended action.  I have tried returning false from the click method, but it does not work.  I think it might have to do with the fact that the button is embedded under two div elements and it's bubbling up.

My button code is:

```
<div class="col__7-12">
    <button class="u__right u__text--alternate  u--paddingTop" (click)="cancelClicked()" >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The canceClicked() method is:

```
cancelClicked(){
    window.history.back();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: while calling the `cancelClicked()` use parameter `$event` and write this way method  `cancelClicked(event){
    window.history.back();
    event.preventDefault(); 
}`

Comment: let me know if you have any issue..

Comment: Are you using the router?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try using: `window.history.go(-1)`
and as mentionned in the comment make sure to preventDefault()

Comment: It was my understanding that return false would also work.  I'm using Angular 2, not 1 so I'm not sure if passing event works the same way?  It was giving me an error saying $event was undefined in the canceClicked method.